# Chat TCP won't sent to both clients

Tags: java, tcp, chat

I'm trying to create a TCP chat. My problem is that if there are 2 users with the chat, every time I write a message in the chat I am sent to the server but the other chat does not. I do not know why someone can help me like that. I leave here my code.

If I write in a chat, it is sent to me (see image)
[image]

But when I write in the other chat, I'm not sent (see image)
[image]

Client

```
public class Cliente extends JFrame {

public Cliente() {
    setBounds(600, 300, 280, 400);
    LaminaMarcoCliente milamina = new LaminaMarcoCliente();
    add(milamina);
    setVisible(true);
}

}

class LaminaMarcoCliente extends JPanel implements Runnable {

private JTextField campo1, nick, ip;
private JButton miboton;
private JTextArea areadechat;

public LaminaMarcoCliente() {

    nick = new JTextField(5);
    add(nick);

    JLabel texto = new JLabel("CLIENTE");
    add(texto);

    ip = new JTextField(10);
    add(ip);

    areadechat = new JTextArea(16, 21);
    add(areadechat);

    campo1 = new JTextField(20);
    add(campo1);
    miboton = new JButton("Enviar");
    EnviaTexto mievento = new EnviaTexto();
    miboton.addActionListener(mievento);
    add(miboton);

    Thread hilocliente = new Thread(this);
    hilocliente.start();

}

private class EnviaTexto implements ActionListener {

    private DataOutputStream flujoDeSalida;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



        try {

            Socket socketcliente = new Socket("Localhost", 9999);

            //Instancio la clase Mensaje
            Mensaje mensaje = new Mensaje();
            //Utilizo los getter y setters Clase Mensaje y pasamos lo que hay escrito en el cuadro de texto nick, ip y mensaje
            mensaje.setNick(nick.getText());
            mensaje.setMensaje(campo1.getText());
            //Utilizamos ObjectStream para enviar un objeto
            ObjectOutputStream datos = new ObjectOutputStream(socketcliente.getOutputStream());
            //Indicamos el objeto que queremos enviar
            datos.writeObject(mensaje);
            socketcliente.close();
            /*flujoDeSalida= new DataOutputStream(socketcliente.getOutputStream());
            //Escribe en el flujo lo que hay en el campo1
            flujoDeSalida.writeUTF(campo1.getText());
            //Cerramos flujo salida
            flujoDeSalida.close();*/

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        //Ponemos a la escucha el cliente
        ServerSocket escucha = new ServerSocket(9090);
        //Creamos un canal para recibir el paquete
        Socket cliente;
        Mensaje paqueteRecibido;
        while(true){
            //Aceptamos todos los mensajes (Conexiones)
            cliente = escucha.accept();
            //Creamos un flujo de datos de entrada para transportar objetos
            ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
            //Leemos lo que hay en el interior 
            paqueteRecibido = (Mensaje) entrada.readObject();
            //Lo escribimos en el area de texto
            areadechat.append("\n"+paqueteRecibido.getNick()+": "+paqueteRecibido.getMensaje());
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

}

class server:

class Servidor extends JFrame implements Runnable {

private JTextArea areatexto;
private DataInputStream flujoDeEntrada;
private String cadenaRecibe = null;

public Servidor() {
    setBounds(1200, 300, 280, 350);
    JPanel milamina = new JPanel();
    milamina.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    areatexto = new JTextArea();
    milamina.add(areatexto, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(milamina);
    setVisible(true);

    Thread mi_hilo = new Thread(this);
    mi_hilo.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Servidor:Estoy a la escucha");

    try {
        ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(9999);
        String nick, ip, mensaje;
        //Creamos la instancia mensaje para recibir los datos 
        Mensaje recibir;
        while (true) {
            //Aceptar las conexiones del cliente (Exterior)       
            Socket misocket = servidor.accept();

            //Creamos un Objectinput para recibir los datos
            ObjectInputStream datos = new ObjectInputStream(misocket.getInputStream());
            //Meter dentro del objeto datos lo que le llega por la red
            recibir = (Mensaje) datos.readObject();
            //Accedemos a la informacion que hay dentro del paquete donde esta el nick,ip y el mensaje
            nick = recibir.getNick();
            mensaje = recibir.getMensaje();

            /*flujoDeEntrada = new DataInputStream(misocket.getInputStream());
                //Almacenamos el texto del cliente
                cadenaRecibe= flujoDeEntrada.readUTF();
                //Agregar el texto que recibe al textarea
                areatexto.append("\n"+cadenaRecibe);*/
            areatexto.append("\n" + nick + ": " + mensaje);
            //Creamos otro oscket para que viaje la informacion
            Socket destinatario = new Socket("",9090);
            //Enviamos el paquete 
            ObjectOutputStream reenvio = new ObjectOutputStream(destinatario.getOutputStream());
            //Metemos la informacion que vamos a enviar en el ObjectOutput
            reenvio.writeObject(recibir);
            reenvio.close();
            //Cerramos socket
            destinatario.close();
            //Cerramos conexion
            misocket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Okay, step back for a second.  You really only want a single server to coordinate the communications (weather one client acts as the server or you have an independent server to which both clients communicate through is up to you). You would write a message to the server and the server would forward that to the client. This would suggest that 1- Each client should reading/writing from the same socket (not closing it between transmissions); 2- The server would need to keep track of all the clients which are currently connecetd

Comment: @MadProgrammer 
I do not get it

Comment: Then you need to do more research into the subject, which is beyond the scope of SO - I'd recommend starting with [All About Sockets](CaptainCrewOptionModeTableViewKitSection). I'd also recommend that you simplify you code to remove the UI while you come to grasp with the concepts, as it's just another added layer of complexity

Comment: Netbeans won't be there at runtime: it isn't part of your requirment; and there is no evidence here that it is part of your priblem either. Don'tt tag indiscriminately.